# GStreamer RTSP Server with TLS Example Fails

Tags: c, gstreamer, glib

I am trying to use GStreamer 1.7.1 to start an RTSP server with authentication and TLS support. The code I am using is nearly identical to the [file from source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/examples/test-video.c?id=7374976722852c93e59c3cee2a562f947cb7f310), except for having `#define WITH_AUTH` and `#define WITH_TLS`.

I start the server using `./test-video` after compilation while inside the examples directory.

To access the stream, I am connecting from the same machine using the following line in Terminal:
`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsps://127.0.0.1:8554/test user-id=user user-pw=password tls-validation-flags=generic-error ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! osxvideosink`

Once I attempt to start the client, the server outputs these messages:

```
0:00:03.217216000 26896 0x7fe1248159e0 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:733:find_media: client 0x7fe1240208e0: not authorized to see factory path /test
0:00:03.217248000 26896 0x7fe1248159e0 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:2276:handle_describe_request: client 0x7fe1240208e0: no media

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_request_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_request_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_request_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_request_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(test-video:26896): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(test-video:26896): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
```

While the client output is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsps://127.0.0.1:8554/test
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info

** (gst-launch-1.0:26910): CRITICAL **: gst_rtsp_message_take_header: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gtype.c:4272: type id '0' is invalid

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gvalue.c:184: cannot initialize GValue with type '(null)', this type has no GTypeValueTable implementation

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gtype.c:4272: type id '0' is invalid

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gvalue.c:184: cannot initialize GValue with type '(null)', this type has no GTypeValueTable implementation

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_value_deserialize: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (dest)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_value_deserialize: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (dest)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_property: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_property: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_unset: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_unset: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_request_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:26910): CRITICAL **: gst_rtsp_message_take_header: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gtype.c:4272: type id '0' is invalid

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gvalue.c:184: cannot initialize GValue with type '(null)', this type has no GTypeValueTable implementation

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gtype.c:4272: type id '0' is invalid

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gvalue.c:184: cannot initialize GValue with type '(null)', this type has no GTypeValueTable implementation

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_value_deserialize: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (dest)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_value_deserialize: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (dest)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_property: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_property: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_unset: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_unset: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_request_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:26910): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc4: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2948): void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *) (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc4:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.001834000
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I'm currently attempting on OS X El Capitan machine, but I have also tried on a Linux Mint 17.3 box and receive identical messages.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can resolve this issue? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors are likely due to gstreamer or glib not being able to dynamically load modules.

**First Check:**

With any of the TLS functionality, Glib dynamically loads in a TLS module. By defualt this is a gnutls module. On Ubuntu, this is found in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so`. This dependency is provided by glib-networking (https://github.com/GNOME/glib-networking) if you would like to compile it yourself.

**Second Check:**

After the TLS handshake has completed, the RTSP server then proceeds to setup the SRTP channel. If the SRTP plugins do not exist on the system, the program will post CRITICAL errors. Run **`gst-inspect-1.0 srtpenc`** and **`gst-inspect-1.0 srtpdec`** to verify that these plugins exist and that their dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: I was missing the srtp plugin from gst-plugins-bad because neither machine had srtp installed. Thanks for the assistance!